# How to multiply all records of a single field in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to multiply all records of a single field in Access 2010.
I tried `mult(Field name)` and `product(field name)` to no avail.
Can anyone help me is there any function in Access to do so?

Example:
I have a table having the field S1

```
S1 
---
557
560
563
566
569
572
575
578
581
```

and the output should be in another table having the field result

```
Result
--------
6.25E+24
```

Comment: Some example data would help.

Comment: As I have a table having the field S1 and i want to mutilple all the values of this column S1

S1
557
560
563
566
569
572
575
578
581

Comment: Please add that and the expected output formatted to your question.

Comment: and the output should be in another table having the field result



Result
6.25E+24

Comment: As I said please add all that directly to your question. And use the `{}` button to format your code.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no `PRODUCT()` function in Access SQL that would allow you to do

```
SELECT PRODUCT([S1]) AS Result FROM [YourTable]
```

However, you can use VBA to "roll your own" `DProduct()` domain aggregate function, similar to the built-in `DSum()` function:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function DProduct(Expr As String, Domain As String, Optional criteria) As Variant
    Dim SQL As String, Result As Double
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
    On Error GoTo DProduct_Error
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    SQL = "SELECT " & Expr & " AS Expr1 FROM [" & Domain & "]"
    If Not IsMissing(criteria) Then
        SQL = SQL & " WHERE " & criteria
    End If
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
        DProduct = Null
    Else
        Result = 1
        Do Until rst.EOF
            Result = Result * rst!Expr1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
        DProduct = Result
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Exit Function

DProduct_Error:
    DProduct = Null
End Function
```

Testing with the sample data in your question

```
?DProduct("S1", "YourTable")
 6.24666417941851E+24
```